# How do I create a common symbology scale for multiple rasters in QGIS/ArcGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, raster, symbology

I have twelve global surface temperature rasters and each has a slightly different temperature range depending on the time of year. I would like to create a common scale i.e. -80c to 80c and so all the colours in each raster match each other. I am happy it do this in either QGIS or ArcGIS.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: Asking about two products in one question is effectively asking two questions which goes against the [Tour].

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know this question had been asked before. I did not intend to break any forum roles, so sorry about that. I have now read the Tour.